# ¿como diseñar un Select MULTIPLE con CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

```
<body>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <br/><br/>
    <label>DNI</label>
    <input type="text" id="dni"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>APELLIDO</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>CELULAR</label>
    <input type="text" id="numero"><br/>
    <br/><br/>

    <select class="test" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple">
       <option>2G</option> 
       <option>3G</option> 
       <option>4G</option> 
       <option>TDD</option>
   </select>
      </br></br>

    <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="anadir()" value="anadir">
    <input type="submit" onclick="modificar()" value="modificar">
    <input type="submit" onclick="eliminar()" value="eliminar">
    <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me muestra de esa manera, pero lo que deseo es que me muestre el Select Multiple pero con diseño, osea que cada opcion presente a su lado izquierdo un cuadro para dar check, lo que es el AJAX Y JSON ya realize el codigo, pero el interfaz de el select multiple debe ser distinto, osea que si por ejemplo tenga una lista de 1000 datos,se habra mediante una menu desplegable

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un plugin, por ejemplo Select2

Comment: ¿Has hecho la misma pregunta varias veces?

Comment: @alanfcm he intentado hacerlo con un plugin, y el diseño sale muy bueno, pero el problemas es que cuando llamo valores con el JSON no me muestra en el select multiple... osea no me salen los check marcados

Comment: Podrias hacer otra pregunta para ese problema.  Chequea la documentacion para ver como le das valor a un Select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar algo de Jquery

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <select size="5" name="lstStates" multiple="multiple" id="lstStates">
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    </select>   
</body>
```

**DONDE DETERMINAS LA ACCION**

```
$(function () { 
    $('#lstStates').multiselect({ 
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            console.log(select[0].length);
            if (options.length === 0) {
                return 'Sin Seleccion';
            }
            if (options.length === select[0].length) {
                return 'Todos ('+select[0].length+')';
            }
            else if (options.length >= 4) {
                return options.length + ' Seleccionados';
            }
            else {
                var labels = [];
                console.log(options);
                options.each(function() {
                    labels.push($(this).val());
                });
                return labels.join(', ') + '';
            }
        }

    });


});
```

[EJEMPLO REALIZADO](http://jsfiddle.net/30eaador/1/)

Comment: esa funcion lo creaste con un script en el mismo cuerpo del html?

Comment: puedes usar de las dos formas, es decir incluido en el html o con un script externo eso dependera de ti, igual va a funcionar

Comment: lo estuve haciendo de esa manera pero no me resulta, estoy haciendo en el mismo html, estoy incluyendo un <script> despues del </select> pero no varia,el select multiple sigue mostrandose igual como en la imagen... o es que falta añadir algo en el head?

Comment: he añadido bootstrap, y multiselect y corre muy bien en mi codigo, pero no me muestra los valores que recojo de mi base de datos, ya que el js solo muestra valores que se seleccionan con el mouse... formulare otra pregunta para que se entienda

Comment: en tu codigo he visto que usas estas librerias        jquery-1.11.3.min.js 
  bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.min.js
bootstrap-multiselect.css 
bootstrap-multiselect.js        pero hay alguna manera que no trabaje con alguna de ellas?

Comment: si deseas usas bootstrap sino no lo uses, pero lo que si hago en mi codigo es usar jquery, todo depende de ti y tus necesidades..!!

Comment: claro, como lo estpy haciendo en php nativo tengo que descargar las librerias, y tambien he probado para no usar bootstrap, sino que se distorciona el multiselect, por eso pregunte si habia otra manera de diseñar

Answer (score 0):

otra manera mas facil de crear el `select`multiple es implementando la librería `select2` te dejare el enlace de la librería para que veas como funciona [select2](https://select2.org/)